# How to connect AWS Keyspace using Django Cassandra Engine?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-models, cassandra, amazon-keyspaces

I am trying to set a django app and connect it to AWS Keyspaces.
Trying to do it using django-cassandra-engine.

I'm currently using this setup in the settings, but it's not working.

```py
    ssl_context = SSLContext(PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    ssl_context.load_verify_locations('/Users/amit/sf-class2-root.crt')
    ssl_context.verify_mode = CERT_REQUIRED

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_cassandra_engine',
        'NAME': 'Keyspace Name',
        'HOST': 'Cluster()',
        'connection': {
            'port': 9142,
            'contact_points': ['cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'],
            'ssl_context': ssl_context,
            'auth_provider': PlainTextAuthProvider(username='USERNAME',password='PASSWORD')

        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
 File "/Users/amit/workspace/eventHandler/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_cassandra_engine/connection.py", line 78, in register
connection.get_connection(name=self.alias)
```

File "/Users/amit/workspace/eventHandler/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/connection.py", line 247, in get_connection
raise CQLEngineException("Connection name '{0}' doesn't exist in the registry.".format(name))
cassandra.cqlengine.CQLEngineException: Connection name 'default' doesn't exist in the registry.

Comment: Please show us what you're tried so far.

Comment: @Maurice : edited body above with current usage

Comment: What is the error message you're seeing?

Comment: @Maurice updated above. Checked keyspace is up as I am able to connect using a seperate python script using cassandra driver but, not through database entry in settings.py file in django project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out:-

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django_cassandra_engine',
    'NAME': 'KEYSPACE_NAME',
    'HOST': 'cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'replication': {
            'strategy_class': 'SimpleStrategy',
            'replication_factor': 1
        },
        'connection': {
            'port': 9142,
            'ssl_context': ssl_context,
            'auth_provider': PlainTextAuthProvider(username='USERNAME',
                                                   password='PASSWORD')

        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Keyspaces or Cassandra, but from looking at the [endpoint documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/programmatic.endpoints.html) and [python examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/using_python_driver.html) in AWS, I'm guessing that the port should be `9142` instead of `9042`.

Comment: I am trying to give a cluster in host as mentioned in syntax but, same is not working. Have updated in body above  for reference

Comment: updated the post ...looks like a syntax error. I have not used Cluster as a host entry before so looks like I am missing the syntax for that

Comment: What's the error message if you take your original configuration and just change the port number to 9142?

Comment: Changed port to 9142 still it tries to connect to 9042 Error: cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'3.234.248.206:9042': OSError(None, "Tried connecting to [('3.234.248.206', 9042)]. Last error: timed out")})

Comment: Figured out. Thanks for trying and helping :) Highly appreciated